# How to call a method in another view when controller is dismissed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, methods

Basically the problem I am having is I am unable to call a method in my Main view controller(called Recorder) from another view called Table.

The table view is loaded as a Modalview controller(presentmodalViewController) from Recorder when the user clicks on a button. The table view lets my users change from setting 1 to setting 2 and has a done button (which calls dismissmodalviewcontroller) and returns the user to the main view(Recorder).

What I want is to call a method in Recorder when the done button is clicked on Table View. This method is called Changeview and changes the setting. I am currently unable to call this method properly.

The current code I have is:

**changeView method**

```
- (void)changeView
{

    [levelsView changeView];

}
```

**TableViewController interface file**

```
RecorderViewController*recorderViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) RecorderViewController *recorderViewController;
```

**TableViewController implementation file**

```
@synthesize recorderViewController;

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        [recorderViewController changeView];

    }
```

**Method called when Done button is pressed**

```
- (IBAction) Switch: (id) sender { 

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

The current code does not give me any errors but it also does not change the setting. I have also tried to setup notifications with no luck. Any insight into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the value of recorderViewController when you initialize the tableViewController (i.e., are you setting `tableViewController.recorderViewController = self` in your Recorder class)? If not, then your call to `[recorderViewController changeView]` is sending a message to nil – which doesn't crash, but it doesn't do anything either.

As an aside, passing your TableViewController a reference to your RecorderViewController is probably not the best way for two controllers to communicate: You may want to consider using [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNotificationCenter), or passing a model object and using [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Comment: Hi Scott,You were right I didn't set tableviewcontroller.recorderviewcontroller=self. That has fixed my problem. Thanks so much for help. I will look into key-value observing too.